# laravel getting the page isn’t redirecting properly error when validation fails on page2

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-10

I am working on a multi-step form which I want to design page by page.

The first page is working fine but the second page shows the following error if there is validation error.

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

My codes

First form

```
<form method="post" action="{{url("page-2")}}">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div>
       <input type="text" name="first_name" />
  </div>
  <div>
       <input type="text" name="last_name" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">next</button>
</form>
```

Routes

```
Route::any('page-2', ['uses' => 'Home\HomeController@page2']);
```

controller

```
public function page2(){
   $request->validate([
      "first_name" => "required",
      "last_name" => "required",
   ]);
   return view("page2")
}
```

Second form

```
<form method="post" action="{{url("page-3")}}">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div>
       <input type="text" name="address" />
  </div>
  <div>
       <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">next</button>
</form>
```

Routes

```
Route::any('page-3', ['uses' => 'Home\HomeController@page3']);
```

Controller

```
public function page3(){
   $request->validate([
      "address" => "required",
      "date_of_birth" => "required",
   ]);
   return view("page3")
}
```

Third form

```
<form method="post" action="{{url("page-4")}}">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div>
       <input type="text" name="category" />
  </div>
  <div>
       <input type="text" name="skills" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If those forms are inside a `.blade.php` your url(s) should be `{{ url("page-2") }}` instead of `url("page-2")`

Comment: @brombeer I have updated my code. the same issue

Comment: How do you serve your project? Have you tried adding https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf to your forms?

Comment: I have tried  {{ csrf_field() }} the same issue

Comment: any reason you are using route any? what are the routes used to access the views?

Comment: @suxgri exactly he needs to be use the `post route` not `any` if there is no specific reason.

Comment: @suxgri I am using post.

Comment: you must have a get/view route to get to the initial form (page-1 i suppose), can you post it?

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanAli The `any` route includes `get` and `post`

Comment: @suxgri "_The first page is working fine_" sounds like ... the first page is working fine - and why wouldn't it, `any` includes `get`

Comment: @brombeer, sure, i tested the code and it runs, so i thought the error, if any, has to be somewhere else

Comment: also noted $request should be undefined in your controller methods